# Woocommerce Child Category Permalink Structure Change

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Woocommerce and WordPress latest version. Basically, I am using WordPress multisite function with woocommerce where sub directory are country.In a nutshell, it is a multi-country ecommerce store.

Following are some of the permalinks where I have same child for multiple categories. Due to how WordPress work, I can not create assign single child to multiple categories. Let me explain this with an example to make it more clear.

My website is https://giftsluv.com.

I have following categories

Flowers
Cake
Chocolate

Now, there is a sub category or child category named

Birthday

assigned to Flowers category. In such situation my permalink would be mysite.com/product-category/flowers/birthday

If I create a new Birthday sub category or child category in cake, it would look something like this

mysite.com/product-category/cake/birthday-cake

I would like to display above permalinks like

mysite.com/product-category/birthday-cake

In this example, the product category is removed as it creates a very long permalink structure which is not ideal in terms of SEO and user experience. Please help me to solve this.

Most of the permalink plugins work on WordPress but they do not seem to work on Woocommerce.

Comment: In short you need to achieve something like `category/subcategory/post-title/`, right ?

Comment: Not exactly, let me put an example

Example: https://giftsluv.com/send/flowers-delivery/ (this is category)
https://giftsluv.com/send/flowers-delivery/birthday/ (this is sub category)


https://giftsluv.com/send/balloons-delivery/ (this is category)
https://giftsluv.com/send/balloons-delivery/birthday-balloons-delivery/ (this is sub category)



In above example, if it is possible can you change the permalink structure of sub category to


https://giftsluv.com/send/birthday-balloons-delivery/ (2nd example from above)